# Folder path of System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments of Xamarin.Android in windows

Tags: c#, android, filepath, special-folders, xamarin-android-player

In my Xamarin Android app I am storing screen shots in the following path System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments. When I am running the app on windows simulator, where exactly this file get stored ? I searched almost my entire systen but no luck. I refered to many links on internet no luck again. where exactly I can see this data on windows 10 system. The file path I am setting it as using following code is 
string filepath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)+"/Screen1.png";

while debugging I can see the value of filepath as "/data/user/0/ArcGISAndroid.ArcGISAndroid/files/Screen1.png"

When I am tryiing with A local directory in app I am getting follow error :{Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\T\sampless.png: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) ---> Android.Systems.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.

Is their a way in Xamarin.Android to store the files in local to cross check them ?

Answer (score 1):

You can push and pull files to a virtual sd folder from the SD card tab of the advanced tools options.

See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/

Answer (score 0):

The file is not stored on the Windows but on the virtual machine that runs on it. You can't get it from Windows.

Comment: Is thier any other way to store them on Local directory of the app ? when I am giving some local directory I am getting this error : {Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\T\sampless.png: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) ---> Android.Systems.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment